# Served JavaScript file is blank

Tags: javascript, html, rust, rust-actix

I'm setting up an Actix server that will host a  variety of static files with the traffic of the web applications running through this single server. When I try to serve a file however, it will serve my assets folder and my HTML file but not my JavaScript file.

I've tried using NamedFile to no advantage and I have tried using "./index.js", "index.js", and moving it to its own js folder and trying "js/index.js".

main.rs

```rust
HttpServer::new(|| {
    App::new()
        .service(
            web::scope("/")
            // Checksheet
                .service(
                    web::scope("/checksheet")
                        .route("/save", web::get().to(save_checksheet))
                        .service(
                            fs::Files::new("", "./quality- 
                            checksheet/public/")
                               .index_file("index.html")
                        )                            
                 )
```

index.html

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Quality Checksheet</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Project Structure

```
.
+-- src
|   +-- main.rs
+-- checksheet
|   +-- public
|       +-- assets
|           +-- badge.img
|       +-- index.html
|       +-- index.js
```

When my server is launched and you go to the page the index.js file is empty, but the assets folder has the images used in the page and the index.html page is displaying.

Comment: Have you checked Web Inspector?

Comment: Yes, I have. When I open the file that it says is linked there it is blank. If I open the file directly from the file explorer the JavaScript file is properly linked and working.

Comment: Do you have it open to the internet so that I could check it out?

Comment: Sorry no, I'm developing it locally as of right now.

Comment: Are you sure that `index.html` is pointing to the correct location to get `index.js`?

Comment: Yes, when I open the file on my computer it works fine but when I serve it it is not present. The index.js file is in the same directory as index.html so src="index.js" should be pointing right at it.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant to ask. Are you sure that `index.html` shouldn't be pointing to `checksheet/public/index.js`?